# Call to a member function move() on string when uploading image

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error:

`Call to a member function move() on string`

The view with upload file:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    // other requests in the form
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Fotos</label>
        <input id="file" type="file" class="form-control @error('file') is-invalid @enderror" 
               name="files[]" value="{{ old('file') }}" multiple>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir producto</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```php
// rest of the request
$files = $request->input('files');
if (!empty($files)) {
    if (is_array($files)) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file->move(public_path() . '\img\\' .  $product->name . $i . '.jpg');
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $files->move(public_path() . '\img\\' .  $product->name . '1.jpg');
}
$product->save();
```

If I `dd($files)`:

`array:2 [▼ 0 => "b1.jpg" 1 => "b2.jpg" ]`

I think the `form` is not passing correctly the `file` to the controller. ¿Any mistake spotted?

Thank you,

Comment: Missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this:

```php
$files = $request->input('files');
```

Which only includes the file names. Use this instead to get the `UploadedFile` objects:

```php
$files = $request->file('files');
```

Documentation on handling file uploads can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files).

As mentioned in comments, you will also need to set the `enctype` attribute on your form for the upload to be successful.